# How does advertising improve the utility of a product?

Tags: utility, advertising

In [this](http://faculty-gsb.stanford.edu/sahni/documents/ad_spillovers.pdf) research paper titled: `Advertising Spillovers: Field-Experiment Evidence and Implications for Returns from Advertising`, I come across the following assumption:

> Utility of a product at time t($u_t$) = Awareness about the
>   product($alpha_t$) + Advertising intensity of the product at time
>   t$f(A_it)$

Claim in the paper: (If utility is high, there is more likelihood that the user would buy the product.)

`Advertising intensity` means the number of times the user has seen the ad of the product in a single session on the website.

And the function $f(.)$ is non-decreasing.

So, my question is: **How does the advertising intensity increase the utility of a product?**

(Is it due to the $+ve$ information about the product given to the user through advertising, or did I go wrong in understanding the concept of utility somewhere?)